# Post string request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have this Post request handler in an asp.net core webapi

```
[HttpPost()]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]string value)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(400);
    }
    else
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(200);
    }
}
```

I am trying post a string to it using `HttpClient` from another app

```
using(var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var content = new StringContent("test test");
    var response = client.PostAsync("http://localhost:57316/api/values", content).Result;
    var responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    Console.WriteLine(responseString);
}
```

the request gets received when I debug the handler above, but value is always null, I expect it to be `"test test"`,waht am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why the type of `Post` is void? Shouldn't this return something?

Comment: @Christos yes but it should also work without returning something

Comment: Could you please share the code of `Post`? I think that something in the body of this method is not correct.

Comment: attribute on post is wrong it should be `[HttpPost]` only.

Comment: they are both same. @Neel

Comment: One more thing should `await` not be used before `client.PostAsync` part as request type is async

Comment: @Christos I updated it as it is now

Comment: @Neel that's not the problem since I am calling .Result which will run synchronously

Comment: It could be that your httpclient posts the value as the body. Try `[FromBody]string value` to see if it's the case.

Comment: @KhanhTO tried that already, same behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're not setting an explicit `Content-Type` on the request, it's possible ASP.NET Web API is interpreting it as JSON, but as "`test test`" (by itself, without quotes) is not valid JSON it will fail.

Try one of these:

1. Set the request's `Content-Type` header to "text/plain".
2. Try sending the value as a valid JavaScript string with double-quotes (i.e. send `new StringContent("\"test test\"");`
3. As JSON readers generally don't like single values, you could set the Request type as some POCO and set the string that way.